# Encoding string using cipher table

Tags: java, arrays, encryption, multidimensional-array

I need to encode a given `message` using `cipherTable` and a given `key`. I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with the `encode` method but i'm not sure what. This code:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Prog3Cipher {
    // INSTANCE VARIABLES
    static char[] keyList; // VARIABLE DESCRIPTION COMMENT
    static char[][] cipherTable; // VARIABLE DESCRIPTION COMMENT
    String alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    static String encode(String message) {
        String result = "";
        ArrayList<Character> w = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] m = new String[]{message};
        for (int p = 0; p < m.length; p++) {
            int row = Character.getNumericValue(keyList[p]);
            int column = Character.getNumericValue(Integer.parseInt(m[p]));
            char q = cipherTable[row][column];
            w.add(q);
        }
        result = String.join(" ", (CharSequence) w);
        return result;
    }

    public Prog3Cipher(char code, String key) {
        keyList = key.toCharArray();
        int offset = code - 'A';
        cipherTable = new char[26][26];
        for (int x = 0; x < cipherTable.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < cipherTable[0].length; y++) {
                cipherTable[x][y] =
                        alpha.charAt((x + y + offset) % alpha.length());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Testing only works if using VM argument -ea
        Prog3Cipher self = new Prog3Cipher('H', "BABBAGE");
        assert "PHXXF MQYBPKNJ".equals(self.encode("Happy Birthday"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Happy Birthday"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at Prog3Cipher.encode(Prog3Cipher.java:24)
    at Prog3Cipher.main(Prog3Cipher.java:68)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

the `encode` method takes a cipher table, `cipherTable`, and finds the intersection point of the `row` and `column`, which are found with `keyList` and `m`, and the intersection is set to `q` and then added to an Arraylist `w`. `Result` is set to a String and returned.

i'm not sure what's wrong as there are no errors with the code so if anyone could look over it and give some guidance it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the likely culprit.

`int column = Character.getNumericValue(Integer.parseInt(m[p]));`

The `NumberFormatException` is from the `Integer.parseInt()`.  If you inspect `m[p]` you'll find that it is an array of length 1 with an where `m[0]="Happy Birthday"`.  The String "Happy Birthday" can't be parsed as a number, thus the exception.

If you want to break a String into its individual characters, you could use [`String.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) like this:  `char[] m = message.toCharArray();`

There are some other issues in your code:

- In the `main()` method an instance of `Prog3Cipher` is being created, but `encode()` is static, so the call to `self.encode()` likely isn't working as you might expect.  Removing `static` from the method declaration of `encode()` should fix that problem.
- [`Character.getNumericValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) returns the [unicode value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) of the provided character.  That method returns 10 for 'A' through 35 for 'Z', so the values don't match the bounds of your `cipherTable` array.
- As written, the `for` loop in `encode()` will walk past the end of the `keyList[]` array.  This is because `keyList[]` only has 7 characters compared to the 14 chars in `message`.
- The `encode()` method doesn't have any special handling for spaces in `message`, so they'll most likely also cause an exception.